# Python Function Call

Tags: python-2.7

```
EtoF = {'bread': 'du pain', 'wine': 'du vin',\
'eats': 'mange', 'drinks': 'bois',\
'likes': 'aime', 1: 'un',\
'6.00':'6.00'}

def translateWord(word, dictionary):
    if word in dictionary:
        return dictionary**[word]**
    else: 
        return word
```

I am working on a simple problem.  I do not understand why I need to have - [word] - in the code.  More specifically, I know if I take it out it will print the entire dictionary but I do not understand the logic of why it has to be there.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Here is a link to the code http://codepad.org/nLHZUBJW

Comment: so you basically want to know what a dictionnary is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `dictionary` variable is a `dict`. This builtin python type is likely an associative array. You need to provide it a key to get a value.

When you define :

```
myDict = {'bread': 'du pain'}
```

You can do :

```
myDict['bread']
```

That would return :

```
'du pain'
```

You can check out more information about dict [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

Comment: This can be achieved by using the `.get(key)` call as well.

Comment: Thanks.  That helps. I guess I need to do a bit more review.  So much to learn.